# Is using MultiMaps code smell? If so what alternative data structures fit my needs?

Tags: data-structures, code-smell

I'm trying to model nWoD characters for a roleplaying game in a character builder program. The crux is I want to support saving too and loading from yaml documents.

One aspect of the character's is their set of skills. Skills are split between exactly three 'types': Mental, Physical, and Social. Each type has a list of skills under if. My Yaml looks like this:

```
PHYSICAL:
    Athletics: 0
    Brawl: 3
MENTAL:
    Academics: 2
    Computers
```

My initial thought was to use a Multimap of some sort, and have the skill type as an Enum, and key to my map. Each Skill is an element in the collection that backs the multimap.

However, [I've been struggling to get the yaml to work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24433582/1075247). On explaining this to a colleague outside of work they said this was probably a sign of code smell, and he's never seen it used 'well'.

Are multiMaps really code smell? If so what alternate data structures would suit my goals?

Comment: Nice advice from your colleague there.  Takes a veiled swipe at the technology without actually volunteering any useful information.

Comment: I've seen similar structures. Usually in Java it's something like a `Map<String,List<String>>` or `Map<String,Map<String,SomeClass>>`. Doesn't seem like a code-smell to me, if it fits with what you need to do.

Comment: Do all characters have the same pool of skills?  If so, is there any reason that you would want each character to store a copy of the skill type information?  After all, athletics is physical for everyone (or so I assume).

Comment: @robertharvey he did suggest just having each key as a variable... But that doesn't sound great either.

Comment: @jwodder everyone has the same set,  normally.  There are some settings where (for instance) the drive skill is replaced with ride, firearms with archery etc.

Comment: How exactly is the multimap currently structured?  Is it a mapping from skill types to sets of skill names?  A mapping from skill types to mappings from skill names to skill ranks (actually a nested map, not a multimap)?

Comment: @jwodder The key is my SkillType enum, the values are Skills.  The skills have their own class with variables.

Comment: So here's something: what you're achieving and what YAML tries to support have different scopes. It's possible your coworker is trying to say that your data structure doesn't lend itself well to the natural form of YAML (likely a tree of some sort), which is true. However, it sounds like you know and understand your scenario well and that it is very well-scoped. This allows you to make a more tailored choice. As a side note, when does your colleague feel that a multimap is the right choice? This would probably be an interesting conversation...

Comment: @JTrana So not main motivation to using yaml is the way it appears when the document is written, users can manually alter the file whilst away from the app. Also the full size document will be modular (and I'll (ab)use the merge function) so I think it might suit my needs more than it looks from my snippet. As for my colleague they've never seen it used well so they (gingerly) said it *might* be code smell.

Comment: I think you're trying to use YAML to encode both data and domain logic here, which IMO *is* a code smell. YAML is not a DSL, it will rarely exactly map to your domain. If the textual representation of these files is /that/ important, it might be worth writing a bespoke parser, but if this is just feeding data into a more intelligent application then it doesn't matter. You can group/sort/et cetera at runtime, not configtime.

Comment: @phoshi what domain live do you think I'm encoding? I don't follow

Comment: What kind of attribute a given attribute is. That's domain knowledge, not something you want to be configurable. No character is going to want Athletics to be a mental trait, and presumably doing this would break your application. Why does the configuration file need this flexibility?

Comment: @phoshi got you.

Comment: If multimaps were a code smell in general, why would [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/), [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and [.Net (experimental)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/06/20/would-you-like-a-multidictionary.aspx) include them?

Comment: Why not just use structs and hard coded member layout?

Comment: @ThomasEding *wears java hat* what's a struct? ;)

Comment: Just a class whose purpose is bundling members.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of notes:

**Never deserialize untrusted YAML.** In most YAML parsers this allows **arbitrary code execution.** In SnakeYAML, you can prevent this, but you need to be very careful, and the risk seems unnecessary.

Since you just need a key-value store I would recommend JSON instead, which brings me to:

**Use strings as keys,** and convert from strings to enums after loading (You can do this with a switch statement or by reflection.). This avoids the need for calling Java constructors from the YAML parser, and thus eliminates the security vulnerability. The conversion can easily be made where needed, and hopefully will not cause much of a slowdown.

Comment: "Never deserialize untrusted YAML." - Wait, what? Are you saying that YAML has a "execute this code" feature, or that most YAML parsers are incredibly buggy?

Comment: @SebastianRedl [Looks like a little bit of both](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2013/02/04/38738/); YAML seems to allow deserialization into arbitrary object instances, and requires extra work to prevent code execution in dynamic languages